# Processing third party payments (using PayPal) while taking a percentage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, payment

I know it's possible to [sit between a payer and payee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3620864/paypal-transaction-that-includes-a-third-party) using PayPal by just storing payee's PayPal account information.

Is it possible to take a percentage of the that transaction and pay it to a different PayPal account.  Basically acting as a service fee for using our website?

If it helps, I would probably be using [Active Merchant](http://www.activemerchant.org/) for rails.

Comment: We have a client using PayPal and we take a cut of her online transactions. We just have IPN forward notifications to us, an intern drops them in a spreadsheet, and we send the client a bill. So, yeah, if there's a better way of doing this, I definitely want to hear it :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are looking for is called "Chained Payments". You can take a commission from a payment, and the remainder can be split with one or more payees. The original payer only sees you. Chained payments are one of the several types of workflows you can get through the "Adaptive Payments" API.

More info on:

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/

and pages 18 and 19 of the following manual on Adaotive Payments manual at cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/PP_AdaptivePayments.pdf

Comment: Looks like the link above is broken, here is another link which currently covers the Adaptive Payments API and the notion of Chained Payments: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/

Comment: edited and fixed, the comment above is not relevant.

Answer (score 6):

I was looking into this very same scenario, and I believe I've found that it is supported via PayPal's Website Payment Pro API.  It appears as though there are several available use cases, such as:

- Taking a cut, as you described
- Dividing up a single customer payment among multiple payees (so if you have a shopping car where you resell items from several different providers, you can divide the payments up based on who provided each item)

Take a look at the document here and see if it fits your needs.  I'd be very curious to hear how your integration goes, since I'm looking at something very similar for my forthcoming site.

https://www.x.com/docs/DOC-1328

**EDIT:**  You should also take a look at the Adaptive Payments API.  That was the other service I found that may fit this use case...

https://www.x.com/community/ppx/adaptive_payments

Comment: So is the transaction fee taken twice? once when the payer pays it to you, and another time when you send it to the final receiver? or is their API programmed to understand that this you are just a middleman?

Comment: I haven't done any testing or delved into the documentation too deeply yet, as we haven't reached that stage of development.  I would assume, though, that each party taking a cut would probably have to pay a fee, but that it would be based off the amount they are taking and not the total.  I'll try and take a look at the docs today and see if it mentions anything about that.

Comment: Kindly check my similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7858722/error-using-chained-payment-in-paypal-asp-net-sdk

Answer (score -1):

You can automatically charge transaction fees between the payer and payee if you use the Amazon Payment Service. It [explicitly supports](http://aws.amazon.com/fps/faqs/#b4) your business model.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'd really prefer to use PayPal since most people have an account.